# Comparison of database date and current date

Tags: java

DB Date is 11-18-2011 03:40:56 and current date is in the same format. 
How to compare? I have implemented the following but it is not giving correct result.
Below is my code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter=   new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());

if(datenow.toString.equals(date2)){

}
```

Comment: what is date2? Is it String or Date? How do you initialize or retrieve it?

Comment: Are you saving `String into the databse or its a Date` ...

Comment: Instead of string based comparison, why don't you use [Calendar.compareTo(Calendar)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo(java.util.Calendar)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare the string representation of dates but use the actual object.
If `date2` is a `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` you can compare them as is, using `new Date().equals(date2)`.

Just be aware that dates are stored in millisecond precision so you might want to remove the fields you don't want before comparing, or use Apache Commons' [`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html), e.g. `DateUtils.isSameDay(date2, new Date());`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with Thomas's approach; convert the dates from the String representation to a date specific type such as `java.util.Date`, which you can then use for any comparisons you require. Thought I might elaborate with a more specific example for clarity:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// convert to a Date
String dateString = "11-18-2011 03:40:56";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);

// comparisons as required
int comparison = date.compareTo(new Date());
boolean isNow = date.equals(new Date());
```

If your program depends on doing such conversions and comparisons often, I would suggest taking a look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).